# How to login and signup for 3 users /uid separately in the firebase realtime database? By using spinner to choose the usertype in register page

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My login java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://science-eagerness-5aa6a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final EditText username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button login = findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        final TextView register = findViewById(R.id.txtSignUp);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Open register activity
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = username.getText().toString();

                final String pass = password.getText().toString();

                if (email.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please enter your email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    databaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            //check if mobile number is exist in firebase database
                            if (snapshot.hasChild(email)) {
                                //mobile is exist in firebase database
                                //now get password of user from firebase database and match it with user entered password

                                final String getPassword = snapshot.child(email).child("password").getValue(String.class);

                                if (getPassword.equals(pass)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Sucessfully login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    //open adminHome activity page
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, AdminHome.class));
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My register java

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://science-eagerness-5aa6a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        final EditText fullname = findViewById(R.id.Fullname);
        final EditText IcNum = findViewById(R.id.IcNum);
        final EditText email = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        final EditText phone = findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);
        final EditText pass = findViewById(R.id.pass);
        final EditText conPass = findViewById(R.id.conPass);
        final Spinner ChooseUser = findViewById(R.id.SelectUser);
        final Button SignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        final TextView Login = findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.usertype, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        ChooseUser.setAdapter(adapter);

        SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get data from edittexts into string variables
                final String txtfullname = fullname.getText().toString();
                final String txtIcNum = IcNum.getText().toString();
                final String txtEmail =email.getText().toString();
                final String txtPhone = phone.getText().toString();
                final String txtpass = pass.getText().toString();
                final String txtconPass = conPass.getText().toString();
                final String item = ChooseUser.getSelectedItem().toString();

                //check if user fill all the fields before sending data to firebase
                if(txtfullname.isEmpty() || txtIcNum.isEmpty() || txtEmail.isEmpty() || txtPhone.isEmpty() || txtpass.isEmpty() || txtconPass.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "This Field is are required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //check if passwords are matching with each other
                //if not matching with each other then show a toast message
                else if(txtpass.equals(txtconPass)){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Passwords are not matching",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    databaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            //check if phone is not registered before
                            if(snapshot.hasChild(txtIcNum)){
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Phone number is already registerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                //sending data to firebase realtime database
                                //we are using Ic number as uniques identity of every user
                                //so all the other details of user comes under Ic Number
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(txtIcNum).child("fullname").setValue(txtfullname);
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(txtIcNum).child("email").setValue(txtEmail);
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(txtIcNum).child("phone").setValue(txtPhone);
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(txtIcNum).child("pass").setValue(txtpass);
                                //show a success message then finish the activity
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Usrr registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                       }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am creating a voting app on Firebase realtime database. I have 3 types of users. I was conneted to database ready but I don't know how to add usertype in register.java

And I don't know to how to create uid users and also I need uid register that indetify in login page after signup , so that after they identify user in login page and username password it directly goes to users page

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Nope I don't have any errors but I want to connect with 3 users in my login page and register